# MySQL: COUNT with implicit GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

I've been trying to guess how to solve my problem for some time and I cannot seem to find a solution, so I come to you, experts.

### What I've got

A MySQL table with the following structure and values (as an example):

```
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | item_id | attribute_name | attribute_value | deleted_date |
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 |       2 | action         | call            | NULL         |
|  2 |       2 | person         | Joseph          | NULL         |
|  3 |       2 | action         | fault           | NULL         |
|  4 |       2 | otherattr      | otherval        | NULL         |
|  5 |       5 | action         | call            | NULL         |
|  6 |       5 | person         | Mike            | NULL         |
|  7 |       5 | action         | sprint          | NULL         |
|  8 |       8 | action         | call            | NULL         |
|  9 |       8 | person         | Joseph          | NULL         |
| 10 |       8 | action         | block           | NULL         |
| 11 |       8 | action         | call            | NULL         |
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

### What I need

I'd like a query to return me how many items (item_id) have at least one attribute_name with 'action' and with attribute_value as 'call', grouped by 'person', but only counting one of them.

So, if - like in the example, at ids 8 and 11 - there is an item_id with two "action" = "call", only `COUNT` one of them.

The query should return something like this:

```
+--------+--------------+
| person | action_calls |
+--------+--------------+
| Joseph |            2 |
| Mike   |            1 |
+--------+--------------+
```

### The problem

The problem is that I don't know how to do that **in a simple way** that would not make a huge performance increment, as this query will be returning and searching along a lot of rows - and returning a lot of them, too, in some cases.

The only thing that comes to my mind is with nested and nested queries, and I'd like to avoid that.

If I make a `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, it only returns '1' in 'Joseph', because the value is always 'call', **and** if I `GROUP BY b.item_id`, it returns me two rows with Joseph (and, in this case too, it counts both 'call' attributes, so it wouldn't be the solution neither).

### What I've tried

The query that I've tried is the following:

```
SELECT a.attribute_value AS person, COUNT(b.attribute_value) AS action_calls  
FROM `er_item_attributes` a, `er_item_attributes` b 
WHERE a.attribute_name = 'person' 
    AND b.item_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM er_item_parents WHERE parent_id IN (1234,4567)) 
    AND b.item_id = a.item_id 
    AND b.attribute_name = 'action' 
    AND b.attribute_value = 'call'
    AND b.deleted_date IS NULL 
GROUP BY a.attribute_value, b.attribute_name
```

### Additional information

The item_id, as you can see, will be also chosen from an inner WHERE clause, because the ones that are valid are in another table (just like a parent - son table). The parent_id numbers are for an example and are not relevant.

### To sum up

How can I make a `COUNT` in MySQL to behave like a `COUNT GROUP BY` without nesting `SELECT`s that could deteriorate the performance?

If any further information was needed, comment it and I will try to add it.

Also, any recommendations on another way to query the information needed to improve performance will be welcome.

Thank you everyone for your time and help!

Kind regards.

Comment: where is the relationship between person and your table?

Comment: There is no relation. It's simply a value of an attribute that an item has. It's purely a text field. The relation is made in the query, with "a.attribute_name = 'person'".

Comment: yeah get it now. duh

Comment: @Strawberry Which one, what? :O

Comment: This problem stems from poor design. In an eav model (which is anyway inefficient), you should not have multiple entity-attributes with the same value.

Comment: I think that this depends on the aim of the data structure. I mean, those items can have multiple attributes with the same name/category, and it can be interesting too to be able to determine wether a specific attribute category has multiple values repeated depending, again, on the aims. On this purpouse, of course, it's not - and should not - be repeated, but this is for statisticals purpouses, which are not the main target of this structure. This structure is designed to suit other functionalities and, in addition, we want to be able to have these counts. As I said, it depends on the aims.

Comment: Of course, I also admit that regarding to data structure I am anything more than a newbie, and I'm not saying that this data is perfect!! I know it - may, sure will - have some flaws and I appreciate your approach! Thanks for taking the time to answer! :P

Comment: I'm not so sure. I think that if there can be multiple calls associated with the same person then these should be held in a separate table.

Comment: Also, Joseph has three calls. One under entity 2 and two under entity 8

Comment: It can be an approach, too. It would help to organise the data regarding to that person. And yes, Joseph has three calls, but in this example as I mentioned I only need to have the COUNT of those made per item, so if a call is repeated in an item, it should only COUNT as one. As I wrote in my comment, this "count only one" aim is only for this statistical purpouses, but it's not the main functionality of the table. For this reason both - repeated and unique values - may have to be able to coexist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

CREATE TABLE eav_hell
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO eav_hell 
VALUES
( 1 ,2 ,'action','call'),
( 2 ,2 ,'person','Joseph'),
( 3 ,2 ,'action','fault'),
( 4 ,2 ,'otherattr','otherval'),
( 5 ,5 ,'action','call'),
( 6 ,5 ,'person','Mike'),
( 7 ,5 ,'action','sprint'),
( 8 ,8 ,'action','call'),
( 9 ,8 ,'person','Joseph'),
(10 ,8 ,'action','block'),
(11 ,8 ,'action','call');

SELECT e1.entity
     , e1.value person
     , e2.value action
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM eav_hell e1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN eav_hell e2 
    ON e2.entity = e1.entity 
   AND e2.attribute = 'action' 
   AND e2.value = 'call' 
 WHERE e1.attribute = 'person' 
 GROUP 
    BY entity
     , person
     , action;
+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| entity | person | action | COUNT(*) |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|      2 | Joseph | call   |        1 |
|      5 | Mike   | call   |        1 |
|      8 | Joseph | call   |        2 |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Edit:

```
SELECT e1.value person
     , e2.value action
     , COUNT(DISTINCT e1.entity) 
  FROM eav_hell e1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN eav_hell e2 
    ON e2.entity = e1.entity 
   AND e2.attribute = 'action' 
   AND e2.value = 'call' 
 WHERE e1.attribute = 'person' 
 GROUP 
    BY person
     , action;
+--------+--------+---------------------------+
| person | action | COUNT(DISTINCT e1.entity) |
+--------+--------+---------------------------+
| Joseph | call   |                         2 |
| Mike   | call   |                         1 |
+--------+--------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, this is the approach made in my question when I write "and if I GROUP BY b.item_id, it returns me two rows with Joseph, having 2 counts in one of them, which is not the aim". Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: See edit above. An index on (entity,attribute) *may* help peformance

Comment: Perfect! And it seems that the performance is better than @EnriqueMuñoz's answer! I mark it as the answer! (Though, just for everyone looking for the answer, it should have a "WHERE e1.item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM parents_table WHERE parent_id IN (X,Y))" in the WHERE clause. Apart from that, just perfect! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Er, no it shouldn't -  but we can talk about that

Comment: Mmm... I've tried the query without that WHERE clause, and then it shows me ALL the 'action' of ALL the item_ids in that table. Of course, the count in  that "ALL" list is still correct, but gives me records that I don't need. I'm only interested in those records that are in a item_id that has a parent X, for this it must have the WHERE clause to reduce the item_ids set that it's fetching.

Comment: Fine, but that's just another join, not a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
SELECT attribute_value AS person, COUNT(*) FROM `stack_1239` 
WHERE item_id IN (
    SELECT item_id FROM `stack_1239` WHERE attribute_name = 'action' AND attribute_value = 'call'
)
AND attribute_name = 'person'
GROUP BY person;
```

:)

Comment: Mmmm... it works!! Though the performance is slower, but it seems to work correctly. I mark the answer as correct, but if anyone finds another way to improve performance, please comment it! Thank you all for your time and answers!

Comment: Though this answer is perfect, too, I remarked the correct answer to @Strawberry's answer as the performance is better in that one. If I could, however, I'd mark both answers as correct!! Thank you again so much for your time and patience!